# Pandas - replace values without keeping old non-matches

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd

test_csv = """
time,val1,what_new_val1_should_be
2004-07-21 09:00:00,apple,1
2004-07-21 10:00:00,N,
2004-07-21 11:00:00,pear,2
2004-07-21 12:00:00,apple,1
2004-07-21 13:00:00,bread,3
2004-07-21 13:00:00,pear,2
2004-07-21 13:00:00,,
2004-07-21 13:00:00,,
"""

from io import StringIO
test_csv = StringIO(test_csv)
df = pd.read_csv(test_csv)


def coded_val(df):
    """

    Create a new column "new_val1" that has an integer responding to the wor din val1
    :param df: dataframe. A pandas dataframe with column val1 where the values are food items or N for none or lank for none
    :return: daraframe. A pandas dataframe with a new column "new_val1"
    """

    replacement_dict = {
        'apple': 1,
        'pear': 2,
        'bread': 3
    }

    df['new_val1'] = df['val1'].replace(to_replace=replacement_dict, inplace=False)
    return df


df = coded_val(df=df)
print(df)
```

How can I get my function to produce the values like I want?

```
                  time   val1  what_new_val1_should_be new_val1
0  2004-07-21 09:00:00  apple                      1.0        1
1  2004-07-21 10:00:00      N                      NaN        N
2  2004-07-21 11:00:00   pear                      2.0        2
3  2004-07-21 12:00:00  apple                      1.0        1
4  2004-07-21 13:00:00  bread                      3.0        3
5  2004-07-21 13:00:00   pear                      2.0        2
6  2004-07-21 13:00:00    NaN                      NaN      NaN
7  2004-07-21 13:00:00    NaN                      NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to `map`

```
df['val1'].map(replacement_dict)
Out[44]: 
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    1.0
4    3.0
5    2.0
6    NaN
7    NaN
Name: val1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It needs to be a new column called `new_val1` and I want the column to be of type int

Comment: @Vader you have to fill nan by some int and then call `.astype(int)` , `NaN` cannot be a type int

Comment: @Vader int with np.nan will create the mix data type, I will recommend keep as it , PS: np.nan in pandas is float, new columns , just assign it back ...

Comment: @YOandBEN_W I am fine with it being a float then, how do get it in a new column though?

Comment: @Vader df['New']=df['val1'].map(replacement_dict)